# Subtle difference in object creation causes radically different object lifetime?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I'm running an app on Glassfish with the Sun JVM. One of our developers made a harmless-looking change that appears to have wreaked havoc with the system. All he did was to wrap an existing factory method call with another to provide some logging, like so:

```
// Old code
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);


// New code
PreparedStatement stmt = StatementLogger.prepareStatement(connection, sql);    

class StatementLogger {
    static PreparedStatement prepareStatement(Connection connection, String sql) {
        logger.info("Preparing SQL: " + sql);
        return connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    }
}
```

As a result of the change, it appears that the PreparedStatement has a much longer lifetime than it did previously. The statement is closed in exactly the same way in both cases. But with the change, we're running out of database connections.

Certainly the live reference to the statement survives ever-so-slightly longer in the new version. That might give it a slightly better chance of surviving a minor garbage collection. But the difference appears trivial to me. (One frame pop.) Is there something else in the garbage collection that could let it identify the statement as a short-lived object in the first case but would identify it as long-lived in the second case?

What could be going on here?

Comment: Why are you relying on GC to close the connection anyway?

Comment: Normally you should close your statements after use.

Comment: I do close the statements in both cases. But apparently that does not fully release the statement. Because as noted, this seemingly trivial change causes the statements to hang around and occupy connections in the second case. If we leave the server alone for a while, it does appear to clean up some of these, so I'm assuming that GC is involved.

Comment: Wild guess: calling connection.prepareStatement(sql) can be seen as a anonymous reference for a statement and while in a static environment may somehow difficult GC job. Try assign the connection.prepareStatment result to a variable and then return that variable.

Comment: Both, the statement and the connection has to be closed. Once the connection is closed, it is available again, independent of the lifetime of the object.

Answer (score 0):

The only effect on Garbage Collection of this change is that many new Strings are created, and then garbage collected.

when you say you run out of database connections, this has nothing to do with Objects processed by GC. You can still have a leak of Connection objects, but not run out of DB connections. You say you close the connection? Then you will not run out.

Oh and it might be that you are observing the problem now due to a load pattern change, not necessarily due to a code change.